# Why is -(Double.MAX_VALUE) smaller than Double.MIN_VALUE?

Tags: java, double

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double num = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double num1 = Double.MIN_VALUE;

        if (num < num1)
            System.out.println("num");
        else
            System.out.println("num1");
        
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to check which one is smaller and it return num, I was wondering why is it like that with double but not with integers?

Comment: `Double.MAX_VALUE` is a very large positive number. `Double.MIN_VALUE` is a very small positive number, not a very large negative number.

Comment: To be precise [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) represents "the smallest positive nonzero value of type double"

Comment: then why is it not the same in integers, -Integer.MAX_VALUE equals Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: @Galz *"-Integer.MAX_VALUE equals Integer.MIN_VALUE"* it doesn't. `(-Integer.MAX_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE` returns false on my machine.

Comment: `-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE`, however. `-Integer.MAX_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1`.

Comment: @Galz EPSILON is the name of the constant for the smallest double value in .NET. I believe this is just a bad naming decision on part of Java, you will find a lot of them and they are still in the language for backwards compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

`Double.MAX_VALUE` is the biggest finite number that double can hold. (A very large positive number.)

`Double.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest positive number that double can hold. (A very small positive number.)

So `-Double.MAX_VALUE` is a very large negative number. That's a lower number than a very small positive number.

Contrarily, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the most negative number that an int can hold. It has a different meaning from the similarly named constant in Double.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the Javadoc of `Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html):

- `MAX_VALUE` is "A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double, (2-2<sup>-52</sup>)·2<sup>1023</sup>.", that is, a large positive number.
- `MIN_VALUE` is "A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>.", that is, a small positive number.

So, `-MAX_VALUE` is a large negative number, which is less that zero, which is less than a small positive number.small positive number.